# Can't access my admin account

Tags: database

This morning suddenly after hours of work I found my self unable to access admin account, just a blank page without any info.
The anonymous and authenticated users  are logged in normally without any problem , like usual..

The first reflex was to clear all the cache manually from the database,but this drove me to this issue:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/www/includes/database/database.inc:2171 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/www/includes/database/database.inc(2171): PDOStatement->execute(Array) 
#1 /home/www/includes/database/database.inc(683): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array) 
#2 /home/www/includes/database/database.inc(2350): DatabaseConnection->query('SELECT expire, ...', Array, Array)
#3 /home/www/includes/lock.inc(167): db_query('SELECT expire, ...', Array) 
#4 /home/www/includes/lock.inc(146): lock_may_be_available('schema:runtime:...') 
#5 /home/www/includes/bootstrap.inc(433): lock_acquire('schema:runtime:...') 
#6 /home/www/includes/bootstrap.inc(455): DrupalCacheArray->set(Array) 
#7 [internal function]: DrupalCacheArray->__destruct() 
#8 {main} thrown in /home/www/includes/database/database.inc on line 2171
```

I tried to change the theme by removing it from the themes folder but nothing worked.
Any Help please..

Comment: Have you checked other logs? PHP log, MySQL log, system log?

Comment: Honestly no, but i think the stacktrace above is clear..

Comment: Any additional info that you can provide will help people to solve your problem. For example, usually you can see MySQL is dying because a internal limit is reached (say Max Packet Size for example) in MySQL or System log.

Comment: I have a hosted website so I can't change the server parameters. .anyway I'm gonna look for it

Comment: It's unfortunate that you can't access the required config settings to fix the problem, but sadly that's not something any amount of Drupal knowledge, nor anyone here, is going to be able to help you with. If your server doesn't support your site, you either need to move to a better host, or get your hosting company to relax the restrictions they've imposed

Comment: If "*the stacktrace above is clear*" to you, then why not EDIT your question to explain what you see in it ... ?

Comment: @Clive changing the php and Mysql memory is not a solution...they are already 512Mo in each other...

Comment: Please read the accepted answer to the duplicate question. Neither PHP's, nor MySQL's, memory limit are related. `MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET` is set on a server level, so it has to be changed in my.cnf or equivalent, and the server needs to be restarted for the change to take effect. If you're on shared hosting, it's very likely your hosting company would need to make this change for you, unless you specifically know they've provided a way for you to override that value and restart the MySQL daemon

Comment: This website has worked fine for 4 years with the same config, but ok i will ask my hosting company to  do that

Comment: My MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET is 16 Mo, what's the good value?